# How to translate a SQL query with subquery in select to .NET Core query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, mariadb

I have the next SQL native query:

```
select 
    a.id_agente,
    a.alias,
    a.direccion,
    cd.description, 
    (   select te.data 
        from tevento te 
        left join tagente ta on ta.id_agente = te.id_agente 
        where ta.id_agente = a.id_agente order by timestamp desc limit 1
    ) as data
from tagente a 
left join tagent_custom_data cd on a.id_agente = cd.id_agent 
where cd.id_field = 6 and cd.description = $VAR;
```

I have this query in .net core in a controller like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> GetAgentesByPlanta(string idPlanta)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            List<Object> lst = new List<Object>();

            var q =
                from a in db.Agente
                join cd in db.CustomData on a.id_agente equals cd.id_agent 
                where ((cd.id_field == 6) & (cd.description == idPlanta))
                select new { Agente = a, CustomData = cd };

            foreach (var x in q)
            {
                lst.Add(new {
                    id_agente=x.Agente.id_agente,
                    nombre=x.Agente.nombre,
                    direccion=x.Agente.direccion,
                    alias=x.Agente.alias,
                    ultimo_contacto=x.Agente.ultimo_contacto
                });
            }

            dynamic response = lst;

        return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

This controller responds with a json and it's works. But as you can see, the subquery of select is missing.

¿How can I add the subquery in this .NET Core query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eager Loading here modifying @baquilare answer a bit for sample

```
 var q =   from a in db.Agente
                join cd in db.CustomData on a.id_agente equals cd.id_agent 
                join te in db.Evento.AsQueryable().Include(x=>x.Agente) on
                  te.Agente.id_agente == a.id_agente
                where ((cd.id_field == 6) && (cd.description == idConvert))
                select new { 
                             Agente = a, 
                             CustomData = cd,
                             Evento =te.OrderByDescending(x=>x.timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```

> Here again i dont know timestamp is in which table + it is more optimised then current code but can be improved a lot ... a simple advice using ef or efcore i will always advice to use a repository pattern you might be needing system.Linq namespace too

also you can use sp if not strict on efcore   and execute it via efcore thats better for queries like this one

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this doubt in this way:

```
             var q =
                from a in db.Agente
                join cd in db.CustomData on a.id_agente equals cd.id_agent 
                where ((cd.id_field == 6) && (cd.description == idConvert))
                select new { 
                    Agente = a, 
                    CustomData = cd,
                    Evento = (from te in db.Evento
                            join ta in db.Agente on te.id_agente equals ta.id_agente
                            where ta.id_agente == a.id_agente
                            orderby te.timestamp descending
                            select new {Evento = te}).First()
                };

            foreach (var x in q)
            {
                lst.Add(new {
                    id_agente=x.Agente.id_agente,
                    nombre=x.Agente.nombre,
                    direccion=x.Agente.direccion,
                    alias=x.Agente.alias,
                    ultimo_contacto=x.Agente.ultimo_contacto,
                    data=x.Evento.Evento.data,
                    ultimo_data=x.Evento.Evento.timestamp
                });
            }
```

Comment: That's not a good solution. It's the *ORM's* job to generate joins from the relations between entities. You should add proper relations to the entities instead